# How often do season challenges refresh?

Tags: deep-rock-galactic

There are three season challenges and they don't appear to refresh at the same time when completed. Is it once per day at midnight? I.e., in any given 24-hour period only one new challenge will appear at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tracked this over a few days and it appears that **one season challenge is added per day (at midnight) up to a total of three**.

Those challenges can be completed in the same day, but you'd need to wait three 24-hour cycles to have three challenges available at once again.